# Bootstrap 4 custom checkbox in the input-group

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is there a way to remove extra paddings on the right and bottom sides by default bt4 classes or hierarchy? I realize that it could be done by adding extra css, but maybe it's already a part of bt4?

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="menus_settings p-3" data-bind="with: currentItem">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    Prepend text
                                </span>
                                <input name="label">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked>
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
</label>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use class `p-0` as written in [spacing utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/)